# Working from the prompt, but not from the cron job

Tags: debian, cron, debian-wheezy

I created a script which takes the IP configuration as input

`ifconfig | /usr/bin/python "/home/michel/Python/sendIp.py"`

When i type that in in the command prompt, the script gets executed well, and the result of the `ifconfig` script is available in my script.

However, when I insert it in my cron (with crontab -e) like this, it does not read the `ifconfig` input

`* * * * * ifconfig | /usr/bin/python "/home/michel/Python/sendIp.py"`

The input is read in the script like this:
`data = sys.stdin.read()`

Comment: Well, as i new user on these kind of things, the 'possible' duplicate list didn't help me much. I was more helped by Jasons answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path to ifconfig in your cronjob.

```
[~]: which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Comment: Wicked, that works!